# Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies when using google map api v2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am using google map api v2 which needs to refer a library project which contains google play services.But that jar file is already being used in my project and when i an trying to refer the library project it shows the dependency error.is there another way to use google map api or how can i fix this problem ??

Comment: copy past the jar from your projects libs to google play services. Make sure the version of jar are the same

Comment: @Raghunandan is right - you need to make sure both your project and the google play services API are using the same dependency. I would recommend not only copying one into the other, but also take this time to verify that you're using the latest jar and put it in both places. Alternatively, you could put it ONLY in google play (or leave the one that's there) and point your eclipse project to the google maps jar within google play services, deleting the one in your libs folder.

Comment: Also, if you search SO for "jar mismatch dependencies" you'll find a ton of similar questions/answers.